# Yii2 - Add additional data attributes to dropDownList() elements and have it selected?

Tags: drop-down-menu, yii2

Question already exists with answer (below link), but:
1) doesn't work for me
2) doesn't include the added need to have a selected option

- [yii2 how to add additional attributes to dropDownList() elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31907590/yii2-how-to-add-additional-attributes-to-dropdownlist-elements)?

Can help?

IM USING:

```
<?=$form->field($invoice, 'id')
        ->dropDownList(ArrayHelper::map($some_items_array, 'value_field', 'show_field'), [
            'options' => [
                 $some_selected_id => ['Selected'=>true]],
                 'data' => ['attrib1' => "valueA', 'attrib2' => "valueB']
             'class' => 'form-control',
             'prompt' => ''])->label(false);
 ?>
```

I NEED, BUT DO NOT GET:

```
<select name="name">

<option value="value" data-attrib1="valueA" data-attrib2="valueB">text< option>

</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Already answered here > [YII - Add another attribute to dropDownList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19861424/yii-add-another-attribute-to-dropdownlist)

```
$attributes = [
    'attrib1' => 'valueA',
    'attrib2' => 'valueB',
];

foreach ($some_items_array as $index => $att) {
    $dropdownlist_options[$index] = $attributes;
}

<?=$form->field($invoice, 'id')
    ->dropDownList(ArrayHelper::map($some_items_array, 'value_field', 'show_field'), [
        'options' => $dropdownlist_options, /* [
             $some_selected_id => [
                 'selected' => true,
                 'attrib1' => 'valueA',
                 'attrib2' => 'valueB',
             ],
             $some_other_id => [
                 'attrib1' => 'valueA',
                 'attrib2' => 'valueB',
             ],

         ],*/
         'class' => 'form-control',
         'prompt' => '',
     ])->label(false);
 ?>
```

Comment: Thank you. The problem with this is that this presupposes that all of the option value id's are known and finite (in order to be able to declare each). $some_items_array returns a list of items who's length and values are unknown before runtime.

Comment: Ahh.. yes, that worked, thanks!! I had to programitically select a value so used this slightly modified line: 'options' => [$some_selected_id => ['Selected'=>true], $dropdownlist_options].Thanks again!!

Comment: actually adding the $some_selected_id  line to the options didn't work. I'll prob wind up setting the selected value through jQuery.